# Adding rel="nofollow" to external links in posts?

Tags: plugins, nofollow

I've tried three plugins to do this, non of them worked (I'm using WP 3.01):

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-external-links/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-nofollow/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nofollow-external-links/

Comment: I just tested http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sem-external-links/ and it works. Maybe a configuration issue? or a conflict with another plugin?

Comment: You can try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/follow-nofollow-control/ May It works.

Comment: If we are going to plugin recommendations here, I suggest using this: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/nofollow-for-external-link The source code is simple, direct and doesn't add loads of unnecessary features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're experiencing bugs with my own plugin (sem-external-links), be so kind to say how it's not working...

Comment: I don't read it often. I usually stick to reading bug reports highlighted to me by moderators. What's the thread in my forum?

Comment: Hello Denis, I didn't publish it on the forum, but directly to the contact form.  In what forum should I publish this bug report?

Comment: That would explain why it got rejected then. The person who answers in the ticketing system normally sticks to catering to customers, and it seems you didn't provide all the needed details to locate whatever plugin is conflicting with mine. At any rate, please try disabling the other plugins on your site until you spot the culprit.